# multiple foreign keys on a django model

Tags: mysql, database-design, django-models

I am seeking to create a relational database design in Django where one table has relationships with multiple models in the DB.

The sample models are excerpted below.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class District(models.Model):
    state_id = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class County(models.Model):
    county_id = models.ForeignKey(County, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district_id = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    county_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Kiosk(models.Model):
    county_id = models.ForeignKey(County, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kiosk_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    kiosk_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    kiosk_size = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Operator(models.Model):
    kiosk_id = models.ForeignKey(County, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    operator_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The overall goal is to register kiosks and their operators in the administrative territories. All relationships between the models are one-to-many. Administrative territories are hierarchical from the **States-Counties-Townships** which according to the schema design leads to one table having many foreign keys. For example **Township(state_id, county_id)** and **Kiosk(state_id, county_id, township_id)** and so forth.

If such a design is appropriate, then how would i model it in Django such that a single model like kiosk has 2 or 3 foreign keys relating to the other models?

If i attempt to add foreign keys as it appears in the **County** model i get the following error on applying migrations.

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'region_id' to county without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
>   Please select a fix:
>
> 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
>
> 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
>   Select an option:

It is obviously not the way to do it and i am seeking guidance from anyone who might have a solution to this problem.

I am working in **Django 1.10**.

Thank you all.